# client-side gcp api access - API_KEY_INVALID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

it's weekend so I'm trying something new - the goal is to get a web app connect to GCP api using user's credentials and (for starters) let them choose a project and list their compute resources (let's say networks). I guess the way to go is JS Client on client side + oauth2.

I picked the JS client "complete example" from here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example
registered my app, modified id/secret, changed the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly%22)

Now, it works fine if I just hard-code the project and list networks.

But as soon as I try to make a request like:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
        'method': 'GET',
        'path': 'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects'
      })
```

or even **(!)** add "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1" to discoveryDocs -
I get 400 error "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."

I tried different scopes including the broadest https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform mentioned in API Explorer, but to no avail. I obviously can list my available projects and same query via api explorer works fine.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to add an "Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>" in the header. API authentication is deprecated. You can generate this token with your user credentials

Comment: Thanks, but... I use JS Client, so I do not control headers directly. Also, I don't want to use MY credentials, I want to use the access privs of the user using the app.

Comment: It seems I got mislead by the example, which asks to call gapi.client.init() with clientId and apiKey vaguely linking it to creating authorization credentials. So (without thinking too much, unfortunately) I filled it with client_id and client_secret and that makes  gapi.client use provided apiKey as... API key (not too surprising is it). Surprisingly it works for compute, but not for cloudresourcemanager. Not providing apiKey in client.init() seems to fix it, but I need more time to read and verify to provide self-answer here.

Comment: In gapi.client.init(), If you are providing both apiKey and client_id values, are you getting the expected output?

Comment: Srvidya, no - I'm only able to get the projects if I do NOT provide apiKey.

Comment: To list the resources in a project is to use a Service account with  list and get permissions for Organizations, Folders, and Projects on the Organization resource.  For more information refer to [list all resources](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#list_all_resources).

Comment: The **cloudresourcemanager** API does not support API Keys. You must use an OAuth 2.0 Access Token derived from a user or service account.

Comment: @ioo Did your issue got resolved ? If yes, Can you provide the steps you have followed.

Comment: @JohnHanley - thank you, that explains the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here's what works for me:

The example posted at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example includes 2 types of authentication: OAuth2 and Access Token. While both work for Compute, @JohnHanley in comment above points out that only OAuth access token derived from a user or service account works with cloudresourcemanager API (the one used for projects and folders).

In my case it was enough to remove apiKey from gapi.client.init() call, which makes perfect sense since I wanted to use user's account, not mine. The modified initClient() from the example linked above looks like this:

```
function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
      'clientId': gapiClientId,
      'scope': gapiScope,
      'discoveryDocs': [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/v1/rest',
        'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'
      ]
  }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      setSigninStatus();

/* ... */

  })
}
```